# Using Python's os.path, how do I go up one directory?

Tags: python, django

I recently upgrade Django from v1.3.1 to v1.4.

In my old `settings.py` I have

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), 'templates').replace('\\', '/'),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)
```

This will point to `/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/templates`, but [because Django v1.4 moved the project folder to the same level as the app folders](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py), my `settings.py` file is now in `/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/mysite/` instead of `/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/`.

So actually my question is now twofold:

1. How do I use `os.path` to look at a directory one level above from `__file__`. In other words, I want `/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/mysite/settings.py` to find `/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/templates` using relative paths.
2. Should I be keeping the `template` folder (which has cross-app templates, like `admin`, `registration`, etc.) at the project `/User/hobbes3/Sites/mysite` level or at `/User/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/mysite`?

Comment: Cant you just use `os` to `cd` to `../mysite`? Or whatever command you want

Comment: @prelic Hmm? I don't understand. I am trying to avoid hardcoding the path, because I use the same `settings.py` in multiple servers. The only difference might be the database credentials. I was reading the [`os.path` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) but I couldn't find a command that let's you go up one directory. Like `cd ..`.

Comment: @hobbes3 You can just `os.path.join( os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..' )`  `..` means _the directory above_ throughout the filesystem, not just when passed to `cd`.

Comment: @Michael, it is probably better to use `os.path.join( os.path.dirname ( __file__), os.path.pardir)`

Answer (score 396, accepted):

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'templates'))
```

As far as where the templates folder should go, I don't know since Django 1.4 just came out and I haven't looked at it yet. You should probably ask another question on SE to solve that issue.

You can also use `normpath` to clean up the path, rather than `abspath`. However, in this situation, Django expects an absolute path rather than a relative path.

For cross platform compatability, use `os.pardir` instead of `'..'`.

Comment: Is it a bad idea to use `..` or something? Why is this answer getting less votes?

Comment: I don't know why it's getting less votes, but it's what I've always used. It's even defined in the example for [`normpath`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath). Plus, it will traverse symlinks properly.

Comment: Well I like the simplicity! Why the `abspath` though? I didn't use it before and it still worked in `settings.py`.

Comment: Using abspath will just clean it up a bit. If it's not there, the actual string for the path name will be `/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/mysite/../templates`, which is perfectly fine, but just a little more cluttered. It also ensures that Django's reminder to use absolute paths is obeyed. If you're in a different situation that uses a relative path, you should use normpath to simplify your paths instead.

Comment: [This question was just asked regarding migrating folder structure for the new version of Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857364/whats-is-the-best-way-to-migrate-folder-and-files-structure-from-django1-3-to-dj), so you probably should look to that for solving your second issue.

Comment: @Zitrax Do you know of any platforms where this would be different, or is it just there for future safety? (I didn't actually know about `os.pardir`, never actually got to the bottom of the `os` docs)

Comment: @forivall For example classic mac uses '::' instead of '..'. For more versions see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Comment: Use `'__file__'` instead of `__file__` if you are executing this within your python code

Comment: @PrageethJayathissa explain please.

Comment: Without the apostrophe you can get the error `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined` 
Using `'__file__'` instead of `__file__` will overcome this issue

Comment: @PrageethJayathissa That error will only occur at the repl. Changing it to a string is the wrong way to solve the issue. This example is specifically targetting the Django config, which runs as an imported module. When running inside a module, `__file__` refers to the current file path. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do

Answer (score 154):

To get the folder of a file just use:

```
os.path.dirname(path)
```

To get a folder up just use `os.path.dirname` again

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(path))
```

You might want to check if `__file__` is a symlink:

```
if os.path.islink(__file__): path = os.readlink (__file__)
```

Comment: Is there a way to go up `n` folders without having to call `os.path.dirname` `n` times?

Comment: @OriolNieto Yes, as of version Python 3.4+ you can use ```pathlib.Path.parents[levels_up-1]```. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55516779/11021886) for more solutions

Answer (score 98):

If you are using Python 3.4 or newer, a convenient way to move up multiple directories is [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

full_path = "path/to/directory"
str(Path(full_path).parents[0])  # "path/to"
str(Path(full_path).parents[1])  # "path"
str(Path(full_path).parents[2])  # "."
```

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest method.

Answer (score 26):

You want exactly this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.join( os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..' )
```

Answer (score 12):

Personally, I'd go for the function approach

```
def get_parent_dir(directory):
    import os
    return os.path.dirname(directory)

current_dirs_parent = get_parent_dir(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: Be careful this answer not works if input contains trailing slash, e.g. `os.path.dirname('/tmp/lala/')` still return `'/tmp/lala'`

Comment: The trailing slash case can refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25669963/1074998

Answer (score 12):

If you prefer a one-liner for getting the parent directory, I'd suggest this:

```
import os
    
parent_dir = os.path.split(os.getcwd())[0]
```

`os.path.split()` method returns a tuple (head, tail) where tail is everything after the final slash. So the first index is the parent of your absolute path.

Answer (score 9):

I think the easiest thing to do is just to reuse dirname()
So you can call

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname( __file__ ))
```

if you file is at /Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/templates/method.py

This will return "/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite"

Answer (score 7):

```
from os.path import dirname, realpath, join
join(dirname(realpath(dirname(__file__))), 'templates')
```

**Update:**

If you happen to "copy" `settings.py` through symlinking, @forivall's answer is better:

```
~user/
    project1/  
        mysite/
            settings.py
        templates/
            wrong.html

    project2/
        mysite/
            settings.py -> ~user/project1/settings.py
        templates/
            right.html
```

The method above will 'see' `wrong.html` while @forivall's method will see `right.html`

In the absense of symlinks the two answers are identical.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this approach? It works nice and look nice but a little hackish ;)

Comment: It is slightly different from the accepted answer in how it deals with the links. They are identical otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

This might be useful for other cases where you want to go x folders up. Just run `walk_up_folder(path, 6)` to go up 6 folders.

```
def walk_up_folder(path, depth=1):
    _cur_depth = 1        
    while _cur_depth < depth:
        path = os.path.dirname(path)
        _cur_depth += 1
    return path
```

Comment: Could just use `for _ in xrange(depth)` instead of keeping track of the local variable.

Answer (score 6):

Go up a level from the work directory

```
import os
os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
```

or from the current directory

```
import os
os.path.dirname('current path')
```

Answer (score 4):

To go `n` folders up... run `up(n)`

```
import os

def up(n, nth_dir=os.getcwd()):
    while n != 0:
        nth_dir = os.path.dirname(nth_dir)
        n -= 1
    return nth_dir
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised handling for an arbitrary number of ".." parent directory tokens in a path string isn't directly handled for by the os library. Here's a quick and dirty function that'll give you an absolute path string from a relative one:

```
def get_abs_from_relpath(relpath:str) -> str:
    ap = os.path.abspath(__file__).split("/")[:-1]
    sp = relpath.split("/")
    sp_start_index = 0
    for slug in sp:
        if slug == "..":
            ap.pop(-1)
            sp_start_index += 1
        else:
            return "/".join(ap+sp[sp_start_index:])
```

You can call it with open() like this:

```
with open(get_abs_from_relpath('../../../somedir/myfile.txt')) as f:
    foo = f.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

For a paranoid like me, I'd prefer this one

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    __file__.rsplit('/', 2)[0] + '/templates',
)
```

Comment: perhaps instead of `'/'` you should use `os.sep`

Answer (score 2):

With using `os.path` we can go one directory up like that

```
one_directory_up_path = os.path.dirname('.')
```

also after finding the directory you want you can join with other file/directory path

```
other_image_path = os.path.join(one_directory_up_path, 'other.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

From the current file path you could use:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..','img','banner.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course: simply use `os.chdir(..)`.

Comment: wont work in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

> Not an answer but a long tangential comment that probably should be made as someone may be led astray...

The syntax `os.path.join( os.path.dirname( __file__ ), 'foo.txt')` to get a file within the same folder as the python file getting run is not the "advised" solution for packages, instead package data is preferred for a couple of reasons, for example in a zip packaged package or a more complicated filesystem.

`pkg_resources.read_text(__package__, 'foo.txt')` was the formerly recommended solution, but will be removed at some point and `importlib.resources.read_text(__package__, 'foo.txt')` is the recommended way —see https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources for the many options.
However, this

- requires `include_package_data=True` and `package_data` with a `Dict[str, List[str]` in the `setup.py` file
- requires a `MANIFEST.in` if pip distributed as sdist (but not a built wheel)
- will *not* work for relative imports (i.e. not installed)
- is wisely and generally ignored for sake of sanity in webapps due to the way they run