# How to acess files in other directory

Tags: python

My path is   **/cygdrive/c/Users/MyAccount/MyBox/myDev/trunk**

My python scripts are located in  **/cygdrive/c/Users/MyAccount/MyBox/myScript/delivery**

I want to get list of all files in python script folder as follows:

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print('script_dir %s' % script_dir)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(script_dir):
    for file_name in files:
        print(file_name)
```

I can't get it work because my script_dir prints :

> script_dir /cygdrive/c/Users/MyAccount/MyBox/myDev/trunk/myScript/delivery

How can I make it works?

Thanks

Comment: How about using os.path?

Comment: tried but doesn't get the correct path.

Comment: can you try glob module like glob.glob('<directory>/*')

Comment: @mig-25 foxbat : the problem is to have the path of the <directory>

Comment: Something is wrong with your `abspath`, but can't be reproduced on my machine. What's the output if you `print os.path.abspath(__file__)`?

Comment: @zhangxaochen : the result is /cygdrive/c/Users/MyAccount/MyBox/myScript/delivery/deliverymachine.py

Comment: The problem is that the script can't translate **/cygdrive/c/Users/MyAccount/MyBox/myDev/trunk/../../myScript/delivery**

Comment: @user2961311 then there must be no `myDev/trunk/` parts in `script_dir` as you mentioned in your question. Are you sure about that?

Comment: os.path.join should help. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856683/using-pythons-os-path-how-do-i-go-up-one-directory

Comment: @zhangxaochen i am sure !

Comment: @zhangxaochen I wrote a wrong result. os.path.abspath(__file__) gives me /cygdrive/c/Users/MyAccount/MyBox/myDev/trunk/myScript/delivery/deliverymachine.py

the result is wrong, can't understand why !

Comment: @user2961311 sorry cannot reproduce such an error. plz do not show the outputs/errors **manually**, just **copy and paste** them!!

Comment: I'm guessing now you are using `os.path.abspath(file)`, not `__file__`, where `file` is a hardcoded variable of string in your script. cannot come up with any other assumption ;/

Comment: I put the instructions in a standalone file and there is no problem.
When i use it in my script, I get the wrong path.
I don't get why !
thanks for your help, i'll try another method