# How to calculate relative path in Python?

Tags: python

If I write

```
current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Then I get the path to the current file running.

What I need is the absolute path from the current file to:

```
'../Data/my_data.csv'
```

How do I use `os` to output the absolute path to `'../Data/my_data.csv'` without changing my working directory or anything else?

Comment: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'Data/my_data.csv'))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python's os.path, how do I go up one directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856683/using-pythons-os-path-how-do-i-go-up-one-directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an absolute file path in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use os.path.join:

```
current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
new_path = os.path.join(current_path, '..', 'Data', 'my_data.csv')
```

Comment: And how is this any different to using `os.path.abspath('../Data/my_data.csv')` directly?

Comment: It will depend on if you are running the script from the directory with the file in it.

Comment: + it is more multiplatform solution. Python os module handles proper usage '\', '/' according to the system used.

Comment: Good point, I don't use windows for my programming all that often, but have run into this issue so that is probably the best way to go for generality.

Comment: I've yet to encounter a platform where `/` doesn't work as a path separator.  It works on Windows, Mac, Linux ...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
'{}/../Data/my_data.csv'.format(current_path)
```

Comment: No problem, I find that its a bit cleaner than using '%s' % string