# how to calculate root relative path in Python3?

Tags: python, path, relative-path

The task is to implement a function `root_relative_path(root : str, path : str) -> str`, which calculates the relative path with respect to root, with no intermediate `..` go beyond `root`. e.g., `root_relative_path('/abc', '/../def') == '/abc/def'`

This question is different from [How to calculate relative path in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941315/how-to-calculate-relative-path-in-python) because in this case, `root_relative_path(root='/tmp/abc', path='/../def')` should return `/tmp/abc/def` instead of `/tmp/def`.

Comment: Instead of pointing out the difference to an other question, you should have asked a detailed question itself.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you. I've refined the description of problem.

Comment: I understand why you would like to prevent going beyond root, but why silently dropping some '..' instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: @FrancisColas This function is useful when implementing a HTTP server, where `GET /../../abc` with root=`/tmp/abc` should return files under `/tmp/abc/abc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement your root_relative_path function using a combination of the posixpath and the pathlib modules. The result is

- Platform independent (as long as the root path corresponds to the current platform)
- The path can begin with `/`, `./`, or `../`
- And the path will be normalized using all of the techniques covered by the [normpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) function which includes resolving `..`s.

```
from pathlib import Path
import posixpath

def root_relative_path(root : str, path : str) -> str:
    ''' Calculates the relative path with respect to the root. 
        Any ".."s in the relative path will be resolved, 
        but not in a way that would cause the relative path to go beyond the root. '''

    # posixpath.normpath doesn't work as expected if the path doesn't start with a slash, so we make sure it does
    if not path.startswith('/'):
        path = '/' + path

    # The normalization process includes resolving any ".."s
    # we're only using posixpath for the relative portion of the path, the outcome will still be platform independent
    path = posixpath.normpath(path)

    # Remove the beginning slash so that we're not trying to join two absolute paths
    path = path[1:]

    joined = Path(root) / path

    # Per the OPs requirements the result needed to be a string,
    # But if you're allowed to use Pathlib objects, you could just return joined without converting it to a string
    return str(joined)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import os.path

def root_relative_path(root : str, path : str) -> str:
    return (os.path.join(root,
        os.path.join(os.sep, os.path.normpath(path)).split(os.sep)[1:])))
```

Comment: `return os.path.join(root, *os.path.join(os.sep, os.path.normpath(path)).split(os.sep)[1:])`?

Comment: Adding a `*` before `os.path.join` breaks it. What are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
from pathlib import Path

def get_relative_path(path_from: Path, path_to: Path) -> Path:
    """
    Calculate and return a relative path between the `path_from` and
    `path_to` paths. Both paths must be absolute paths!
    """
    if not (path_from.is_absolute() and path_to.is_absolute()):
        raise ValueError('One or both of the passed paths are not absolute.')
    items_from = path_from.parts
    items_to = path_to.parts
    while items_from[0] == items_to[0]:
        items_from = items_from[1:]
        items_to = items_to[1:]
    return Path(*('..' for x in range(1, len(items_from))), *items_to)
```