# How to move up n directories in Pythonic way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I'm looking for a pythonic way to move up `n` directories from a given directory.

Let's say we have the example path `/data/python_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data`. If we were to move up `n=2` directories we should end up at `/data/python_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages`.

The following works to move up `n` directories:

```
up_n = lambda path, n: '/'.join(path.split('/')[:-n])
```

However, it's not very readable and fails for paths on windows machines. In essence, it doesn't feel a very pythonic solution.

Is there a better, more pythonic solution, maybe using the `os` module?

Comment: I feel like you should use the Path module, better to avoid hardcoding depending on the operating system !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module of the standard library:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('/data/python_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data')

levels_up = 2
print(path.parents[levels_up-1])
# /data/python_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Comment: I feel this is the best solution: cross platform, easy to read and doesn't involve ```n``` calls to ```os.path```. However, since ```pathlib``` is only in the standard library for Python 3.4+, users reading this on an older version of python should consider installing ```pathlib``` with ```pip```.

Answer (score 10):

how about iterating with `os.path.dirname`:

```
import os

s = "/data/python_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data"
for _ in range(2):
    s = os.path.dirname(s)

print(s)
```

prints:

```
/data/python_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use python `os.path` module for this:

```
>>> p = '/data/python_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data'
>>> os.path.normpath(os.path.join(p, "..", ".."))
'/data/python_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages'
```

Or generically for `n`,

```
os.path.normpath(os.path.join(*([p]+[".."]*n)))
```

This way, you don't care it is Windows `\` or UNIX `/` to be used. Python should handle this well. And, you got a one-liner.

Comment: i thought they asked for it to be *more* readable not *less* ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands is right: this isn't particularly readable. Having said that, I certainly don't think its any *less* readable than my initial solution. Anyway, inspired by this solution I came up with ```os.path.abspath(os.path.join(p, "../"*n))```, which I think is a marginal improvement.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to this could take advantage of the shorthand that `..` is the parent directory. So, using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) you could write

```
from pathlib import Path
up_n = lambda orig, n: Path(orig).joinpath('/'.join(['..']*n))
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3.4+, `pathlib` is probably the best choice.

That said, here's something that will also work in older versions (including Python 2.x):

```
import os

def up_n(path, n):
    components = os.path.normpath(path).split(os.sep)
    return os.sep.join(components[:-n])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = '/data/python_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data'
    result = up_n(path, 2)
    print(result)  # -> \data\python_env\lib\python3.6\site-packages
```