# Strip intermediate folders in filepath name (Python)

Tags: python, path, os.path

I have a path `/foo/bar/poo/car` and there are files in the directory `car`.
I want to end up with `/foo/bar` with the same files in `bar`. I realized this is wrong since it doesn't maintain the files:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname('/foo/bar/poo/car'))
'/foo/bar'
```

I guess I would have to first move the files from car to bar and then do the above? Is there a cleaner or easier way to perform this?

Comment: Check this link: [How to move up n directories in Pythonic way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516779/how-to-move-up-n-directories-in-pythonic-way)

Comment: @CavinDsouza Sorry, I have just edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('/foo/bar/poo/car')
bar = p.parent.parent
print(bar)
```

Output:

```
/foo/bar
```

To move files, use [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shutil.html#shutil.move).

Answer (score 1):

You must get all the files absolute paths first with glob. Then you can move these files with shutil.move

```
import glob
import os
import shutil


source_dir = r'R:/foo/bar/poo/car'
dest_dir = r'R:/foo/bar'

# get all file path
all_files_path = glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.*'))

# move the files to the new dir
for file_path in all_files_path:
    shutil.move(file_path, dest_dir)
```