# Equivalent of os.getpardir()?

Tags: python

Is there a simpler way to get a string of a parent directory than doing the following?

```
'/'.join(os.getcwd().split('/')[:-1])
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get parent directory in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860153/get-parent-directory-in-python)

Comment: Please don't assume `os.set == '/'` like that. There are ready-made functions for this in `os.path`: `split`, `join`, `basename`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this would be much simpler for you

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.pardir)
```

or even simpler

```
os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a method that does it but I would do something like:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir))
```

EDIT: This way works but [Ixanezis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10078941/111644) way is probably better.

Comment: os.getcwd() is already absolute path, so os.path.abspath is redundant and os.path.join(x, os.pardir) is almost the same as os.path.dirname(x)

Comment: `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir)` basically just appends `/..` to the path, calling `os.path.abspath` on it then converts it back down. `dirname` is probably a better approach, I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this method may be useful:

```
os.path.dirname(os.getcwd())
```