# python: get directory two levels up

Tags: python, path, operating-system, directory

Ok...I dont know where module `x` is, but I know that I need to get the path to the directory two levels up.

So, is there a more elegant way to do:

```
import os
two_up = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Solutions for both Python 2 and 3 are welcome!

Comment: I think your solution is perfectly fine. A `pathlib` solution is a little nicer and more readable, but isn't included with Python 2.7. I'd say stick with what you've got, maybe add a comment.

Comment: Perhaps worth adding the `pip install pathlib2` option to maintain sanity in 2.7.

Comment: In case you want to get the directory two levels up of your current working directory you can perfectly use: `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.pardir, os.path.pardir))`

Answer (score 212, accepted):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Unfortunately this is only available in the stdlib for Python 3.4. If you have an older version you'll have to install a copy from PyPI [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/). This should be easy to do using `pip`.

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(__file__).parents[1]

print(p)
# /absolute/path/to/two/levels/up
```

This uses the `parents` sequence which provides access to the parent directories and chooses the 2nd one up.

Note that `p` in this case will be some form of `Path` object, with their own methods. If you need the paths as string then you can call `str` on them.

Comment: Thats a nice answer thanks and great for py3. For py2 it is possible not any better than my initial attempt as it creates and extra dependency

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer as the `Path` class's `parents` is dependent upon the execution location.  If you execute your `__file__` from its current directory the `Path` class will have no parents.   Either @Sebi2020's answer should be accepted, or your original method should be used.  I believe your original method is more readable.

Comment: You may need to do `p = Path(os.path.abspath(__file__)).parents[1]`

Comment: @AdamRaudonis Instead of `os.path.abspath`, you can also use `Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]`

Comment: As @Kazanz mentioned, this solution doesn't work when executing from other paths. The best solution is: `p = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]`. I also added it as an answer.

Comment: Be aware that the return type of parents[x] is not a string but an implementation of PurePath. You can always call str on it to get the actual value.

Comment: You need to call resolve on `__file__` like so: `Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]`. Those recommendations to go back to `os.path` calls when we finally have Pathlib are ill advised.

Comment: The answer proposed or any variation with .resolve() like the ones posted here, return `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`. Here's my code just to reassuring what I'm doing: `Brat_Path = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]` Any idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: Never mind. It seems this just work for a file.py, not in a Jupyter or a Python shell for example... I'll add what i think it could be a more general answer that works in other cases too...

Answer (score 81):

Very easy:

Here is what you want:

```
import os.path as path

two_up =  path.abspath(path.join(__file__ ,"../.."))
```

Comment: And perhaps use `os.pardir` rather than `..`.

Comment: does sys.argv[0] not return module that was run by python.exe? So this wouldn't necessary work if the module im interested in was imported from some other package..am I right here?

Comment: If you want to use it in a module instead use `__file__`.

Comment: @jme do you know an OS where you get the parent directory with another string than".."???

Comment: @Sebi2020 Yep, notably the old Mac OS. Here's a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)

Comment: Joining `__file__` and something doesn't always give a valid path.

Comment: @ebk Can you provide more details?

Comment: @Sebi2020 I am sorry that I overlooked the `abspath` part. Your solution has no problem. Because the downvote is being locked by SO until next edit, I will revoke it then.

Comment: I used `up_three_levels = os.pardir + os.sep + os.pardir + os.sep + os.pardir` followed by
`needed_system_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), up_three_levels))`

Comment: Or even `os.path.abspath(path+'../..')`

Answer (score 33):

I was going to add this just to be silly, but also because it shows newcomers the potential usefulness of aliasing functions and/or imports.

Having written it, I think this code is more readable (i.e. lower time to grasp intention) than the other answers to date, and readability is (usually) king.

```
from os.path import dirname as up

two_up = up(up(__file__))
```

Note: you only want to do this kind of thing if your module is very small, or contextually cohesive.

Answer (score 32):

The best solution (for python >= 3.4) when executing from any directory is:

```
from pathlib import Path
two_up = Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]
```

Answer (score 11):

For getting the directory 2 levels up:

```
 import os.path as path
 curr_dir=Path(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
 two_dir_up_=os.fspath(Path(curr_dir.parent.parent).resolve())
```

I have done the following to go up two and drill down on other dir

```
 default_config_dir=os.fspath(Path(curr_dir.parent.parent,
                                   'data/config').resolve())
```

Comment: Location of file and your cwd don't have to be the same. Thus your solution does not always produce the same result.

Comment: Gives the path relative to the working directory not module

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I find that using the os module is the easiest method as outlined below. If you are only going up one level, replace ('../..') with ('..').

```
    import os
    os.chdir('../..')

--Check:
    os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to hardcode the '/'

I would have expected to read os.chdir(os.join('..', '..'))

Comment: Gives the path relative to the working directory not module

Answer (score 4):

More cross-platform implementation will be:

```
import pathlib
two_up = (pathlib.Path(__file__) / ".." / "..").resolve()
```

Using `parent` is not supported on Windows. Also need to add `.resolve()`, to:

> Make the path absolute, resolving all symlinks on the way and also normalizing it (for example turning slashes into backslashes under        Windows)

Comment: Do you have a source for `parent` not working on Windows? This seems to have been fixed sometime since you wrote this comment. It works fine for me using Python 3.7.2 on Windows 10.

Comment: i could get `parent` working on windows 10 with python 3.6.5. Which version of python are you talking about @Zhukovgeen?

Comment: @ggulgulia I believe it was 3.7

Answer (score 3):

(pathlib.Path('../../') ).resolve()

Comment: Gives the path relative to the working directory not module

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly it seems no one has yet explored this nice one-liner option:

```py
import os
two_up = os.path.normpath(__file__).rsplit(os.sep, maxsplit=2)[0]
```

`rsplit` is interesting since the `maxsplit` parameter directly represents how many parent folders to move up and it always returns a result in just one pass through the path.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the following works well in 2.7.x

```
import os
two_up = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(__file__,'../'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this as a generic solution:

```
import os

def getParentDir(path, level=1):
  return os.path.normpath( os.path.join(path, *([".."] * level)) )
```

Comment: @JanSila: can be more specific, why is it not pythonic? For readability, it could have more comments what this does, yes - but in the end it's using standard python language features, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901

Comment: It is a little dense, but I don't think this is too abstract and not readable. It is just a generalized version of other answers posted here. I would like a standard library way of doing things without the need for implementing a function, though.

Comment: Gives the path relative to the working directory not module

Answer (score 2):

100% working answer:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd() ,"../.."))
```

Comment: Nope, that gets the directory two levels up relative to the current working directory, *not* the current module.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to access folder named xzy two folders up your python file. This works for me and platform independent.

".././xyz"

Comment: Gives the path relative to the working directory not module

Answer (score 1):

There is already an accepted answer, but for two levels up I think a chaining approach is arguably more readable:

```
pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent.resolve()
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in some of the other answers. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.

Comment: No, it hasn't been mentioned for pathlib.

Answer (score 1):

With Pathlib (recommended after Python 3.5, the/a general solution that works not only in file.py files, but also in Jupyter (or other kind of) notebook and Python shell is:

`p = Path.cwd().resolve().parents[1]`

You only need to substitute `(__file__)` for `cwd()` (current working directory).

Indeed it would even work just with:

`p = Path().resolve().parents[1]`

(and of course with `.parent.parent` instead of `parents[1]`)

Answer (score 0):

Only with `os.path`

```py
os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"../.."))
```

Answer (score 0):

## pathlib: `Path.parts` is more flexible then `Path.parents`

### what library to use

I would recommend using `pathlib.Path`. Its the modern and object oriented way of handling paths in python.

Hence `pathlib` is the first proposed library for File and Directory Access in the python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/filesys.html

### how to handle paths

I want to point out the option to use the `parts` method. Simply because its a bit more flexible.

With `parents`, you start at the end of the path and navigate upwards. It is not really pratical to get up to the root of the path, as negative indexing is not supported.

With `parts` on the other hand side, you simply split the path into a tuple and can operate on with with all list operations python offers.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path("/a/b/c/d/e.txt")
>>> p.parts
('/', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e.txt')
```

So a small comparison of different usecases with `parts` and `parents`:

```
# get two levels up
>>> p.parents[1]
PosixPath('/a/b/c')
>>> Path(*p.parts[:-2])
PosixPath('/a/b/c')

# get second level after root
>>> p.parents[len(p.parents) - 3]
PosixPath('/a/b')
>>> Path(*p.parts[:3])
PosixPath('/a/b')

# unfortunately negative indexing is not supported for the parents method
>>> p.parents[-3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/space221118/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py", line 620, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError(idx)
IndexError: -3
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't yet see a viable answer for 2.7 which doesn't require installing additional dependencies and also starts from the file's directory. It's not nice as a single-line solution, but there's nothing wrong with using the standard utilities.

```
import os

grandparent_dir = os.path.abspath(  # Convert into absolute path string
    os.path.join(  # Current file's grandparent directory
        os.path.join(  # Current file's parent directory
            os.path.dirname(  # Current file's directory
                os.path.abspath(__file__)  # Current file path
            ),
            os.pardir
        ),
        os.pardir
    )
)

print grandparent_dir
```

And to prove it works, here I start out in `~/Documents/notes` just so that I show the current directory doesn't influence outcome. I put the file `grandpa.py` with that script in a folder called "scripts". It crawls up to the Documents dir and then to the user dir on a Mac.

```
(testing)AlanSE-OSX:notes AlanSE$ echo ~/Documents/scripts/grandpa.py 
/Users/alancoding/Documents/scripts/grandpa.py
(testing)AlanSE-OSX:notes AlanSE$ python2.7 ~/Documents/scripts/grandpa.py 
/Users/alancoding
```

This is the obvious extrapolation of [the answer for the parent dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860153/how-do-i-get-the-parent-directory-in-python). Better to use a general solution than a less-good solution in fewer lines.