# Error while resizing image using open cv

Tags: python, opencv, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create a dataset for training a neural network to authenticate signatures. I encountered an error whlie resizing the images in my dataset.

This is my code so far

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from random import shuffle
from tqdm import tqdm
from PIL import Image

TRAIN_DIR = '../DATASET/TRAIN/'
TEST_DIR = '../DATASET/TEST/'
IMG_BREDTH = 250
IMG_HEIGHT = 100
LR = 1e-3

MODEL_NAME = 'signature-{}-{}.model'.format(LR, '2conv-basic')

def label_img(img):
    word_label = img.split('.')[-2]
    if (word_label == '1') or (word_label == '2'): return [1,0]
    elif word_label == 'F': return [0,1]

def create_training_set():
    training_data = []

    for img in  tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
        label = label_img(img)
        path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR, img)  
        img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), (IMG_BREDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))
        training_data.append([np.array(img), np.array(label)])

    shuffle(training_data)
    np.save('training_data.npy', training_data)

    return training_data
```

I am getting this error

```
 14%|█▍        | 105/730 [00:00<00:00, 1040.64it/s]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-57e881a5e615> in <module>()
----> 1 create_training_set()

<ipython-input-86-ed607a429014> in create_training_set()
     20         path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR, img)
     21 #         img = rotateImage(img, 90)
---> 22         img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), (IMG_BREDTH, IMG_HEIGHT))
     23         training_data.append([unq_num, np.array(img), np.array(label)])
     24         unq_num += 3

error: /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:4044: error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function resize
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone explain the error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This often means that `imread` failed to read an image, which is mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

> Warning Even if the image path is wrong, it won’t throw any error, but `print img` will give you `None`

So it might not be your arguments to `resize` that are wrong, but actually a failure to read the image (maybe a wrong path?) resulting in `None` being passed as the image.

Your path involves using the `../` convention for a parent path, but this might not be resolving to the right directory (depending on the directory from which you invoke the interpreter).

For example, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27844562/567620) (second answer) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2860193/567620) for a solution regarding how to properly reference parent paths from a given file, and as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860153/how-do-i-get-the-parent-directory-in-python#comment24423862_2860200) about why a naive use of `'..'` for parent path might not work as expected (because it can be based on the path from which you invoke the interpreter, *not* relative to the file unless you base it on `__file__`).

If it is getting the right directory, then likely there are corrupted images, non-image files, or other files that are causing `imread` to return `None` .. you might want to add a `try` ... `except` statement in the loop and print out file paths for the case that causes the error.

Comment: you were right. some of the files were not labeled correctly. thank you so much