# How to determine config file path in python?

Tags: python, file, configuration, path

I have a module that needs to initialize some settings by reading a config file. The directory structure looks something like this:

```
root\
    config\
        conf.cfg
    src\
        module1.py
```

I'm fine when I set the relative path to `../config/conf.cfg` and run the module in its current directory. But when I import the module somewhere else and run it in another directory I run into problems.

How should I set the path so the module always looks in the same relative location (eg one directory up from where the module is located) and how do I ensure this works for other people that download my repo (who may not have root in the same place)?

Comment: One way would be to make all paths absolute from the installation root folder and start everything from there.

Comment: How do I set the root folder path? env variable?

Comment: What is `root\` in your example? Is the config file not part of your project?

Comment: root is the root directory of my git repo. The config file is part of the project.

Comment: Then you would define the config path as config/conf.cfg in the module, cd into root and start module by doing python src/module1.py. Depending on what os you are on, this link might also be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860153/how-do-i-get-the-parent-directory-in-python

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

will give you the path of the current file, resolving any symlinks in the path. This works fine on my machine.