# get the parent directory of given subdirectory

Tags: python, path

Any clean way to do path calculation rather than string split in Python?

```
working_dir = "/a/b/c/d/e/f/g", given_dir = "d/e/f/g"
```

How do I get parent path `"/a/b/c"`?

Comment: `working_dir.rstrip(given_dir)`? what have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the parent directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860153/how-do-i-get-the-parent-directory-in-python)

Comment: @Sayse, no way to do path calculation rather than string calculation?

Comment: Thats great. what about the rest of my comment?

Comment: i tried, except treating it like string, not able to find a way to treat it like path.

Comment: @pepero So basically you don't know the exact working directory and you only knows that given_dir  with that you want to find remaining full path , Is it like that ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar, i know working_dir. i just expect something opposite of  os.path.join(), .e.g, os.path.disjoin(path, *paths), or some pythonic way, which could do the path calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The top directory you can get with:

```
os.path.split(working_dir)[0]
```

So you just do that the number of times you need...

Comment: did you read my quesiton? what is the result of your code? "/a/b/c/d/e/f"?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. On the resulting string you can just execute the same command again to get the parent directory of that. Depending on how many levels you want to go up. There are other ways as well. But for finding the direct parent this is the best way.

Comment: sorry, that is not what I want to ask. what if i have "d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m", need ten levels up?

Comment: From my answer you should be able to extrapolate and adapt that example to fit your needs. Strictly speaking, though, everything you want to do is string manipulation which you explicitly do not want to do... So I am unsure how to further help you. String manipulation would also be much more efficient....