# How to get path that ipynb file is running in?

Tags: python, file, path

I have a program that reads in several subfolders of files.

I had previously written code that had :

```
path = 'C:/Users/Me/etc/etc/'
```

And then I would open several files by saying

```
file1 = path + str('file1.txt')
```

How do I change the code so that it can be used by others? I am using Jupyter notebook and so __file __ and sys(argv[0]) don't seem to be working.

I have looked at these:

1. [How to get an absolute file path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python)
2. [How do I get the parent directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860153/how-do-i-get-the-parent-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use get current working directory,

```
def join_current_dir(file):
    """Join filepath with current file directory"""
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    return os.path.join(cwd, file)
```

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook so __file__ does not work