# Import python module from parent subdirectory

Tags: python, module, directory

I tried different methods shown on multiple sites but couldnt figure out the problem. I need to import "demo1.py" in "demo2.py". Here is my folder hierarchy:

```
Project:___ __init__.py
         |_ main.py
         |_ Package1:___ __init__.py
         |            |_ demo1.py
         |_ Package2:___ __init__.py
                      |_ demo2.py
```

When I have this in main.py, it works.

```
import Package1.demo1
import Package2.demo2
```

But this doesnt work in demo2.py

```
import Package1.demo1
```

Neither does this:

```
import Project.Package1.demo1
```

I tried following this tutorial https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/package but Im doing something wrong. Tried renaming "main.py" to something else in case it is causing problems but that doesnt helped either.

Edit: Solution found

```
from sys import  path 
import os

par_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), os.pardir))
path.append(par_dir)
import Package1.demo
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the parent directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860153/how-do-i-get-the-parent-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sys import path
path.append("project-path")
```

Define it inside of demo1 or demo2, it will work. [You may check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860153/how-do-i-get-the-parent-directory-in-python).