# How to remove PythonCode from the path returned by os.path.dirname(__file__)?

Tags: python

I have a python script in PythonCode folder. I want that I should get the path excluding the PythonCode from it when using os.path.dirname(__file__),  currently when I am using os.path.dirname(__file__) it is returning this:-

> C:\Users\xyz\Documents\ABC\Python Code

but I need this path:-

> C:\Users\xyz\Documents\ABC\

import os

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)

print (dirname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap `dirname` once again to go up a directory

```
dirname=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(path))
```

Comment: and how to convert this path returned as C:\Users\xyz\Documents\ABC to this  C:/Users/xyz/Documents/ABC

Comment: You can just do `dirname=dirname.replace("\\","/")`

Answer (score 0):

Just call `os.path.dirname()` again on what you have:

```
import os

dirname = r"C:\Users\xyz\Documents\ABC\Python Code"
wanted = os.path.dirname(dirname)
print(wanted)  # -> C:\Users\xyz\Documents\ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860153/how-do-i-get-the-parent-directory-in-python).

You can do something like this,

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers use `os.path`, but you could also use the standard library `pathlib` module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which some people prefer because of its more intuitive object-oriented interface:

```
from pathlib import Path

wanted = Path(__file__).parent.parent

wanted_as_string = str(wanted)
```