# How to get the path of the parent directory in python

Tags: python, directory, path

I have below directory structure:

```
E:\<somepath>\PythonProject
                        -> logs
                        -> configs
                        -> source
                                -> script.py
```

`PythonProject` is my main directory and inside the `source` dir I have some python script. From the `script.py` I want to access the config file present in `configs`. Here I don't want to mention the full path like  `E:\<somepath>\PythonProject\configs\config.json` a I will be deploying this to a system for which I am not aware of the path. So I decided to go with

config_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**))

But this gives me path to the source dir which is `E:\<somepath>\PythonProject\source` and I just want `E:\<somepath>\PythonProject` so that I can later add `configs\config.json` to access the path to config file.

How can I do this. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the parent directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860153/how-do-i-get-the-parent-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one way:

```
import os 

config_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'configs\config.json')

print(config_file_path)
```

or (you will need to pip install `pathlib`):

```
from pathlib import Path

dir = Path(__file__).parents[1]
config_file_path = os.path.join(dir, 'configs/config.json')

print(config_file_path)
```

third way:

```
from os.path import dirname as up

dir = up(up(__file__))

config_file_path = os.path.join(dir, 'configs\config.json')
```

Comment: like the "up up" way haha

Answer (score 2):

Use `pathlib`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(path_here)

# so much information about the file
print(p.name, p.parent, p.parts[-2])
print(p.resolve())
print(p.stem)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with just os module:

```
import os
direct = os.getcwd().replace("source", "config")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `pathlib` module:

(If you dont have it, use `pip install pathlib` in Terminal.)

```py
from pathlib import Path
path = Path("/<somepath>/PythonProject/configs/config.json")
print(path.parents[1])

path = Path("/here/your/path/file.txt")
print(path.parent)
print(path.parent.parent)
print(path.parent.parent.parent)
print(path.parent.parent.parent.parent)
print(path.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent)
```

which gives:

```
/<somepath>/PythonProject
/here/your/path
/here/your
/here
/
/
```

(from [How do I get the parent directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860153/how-do-i-get-the-parent-directory-in-python) by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4172/kender)

Comment: Why not use a loop? Why not use `parents` that gives all of them? Why reference another question instead of marking this one as a duplicate?

Comment: Thanks @ofer-sadan. I did.
I also needed the reputation to reach 15, so my votes count.