# Check if file is in subdirectory?

Tags: python

I want to check if a given file is within a specific directory and it's including subdirectories .

I used this code :

```
def Grep(givenfile,givendir):
    # iterate top down till in directory path
    for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(givendir):
        if givenfile in files:
            # if file present return true
            return True
    return False

## Test.py my file that contain my code 
##C://Users//LENOVO//Desktop//python2021 this my path that contain my files 
Grep("Test.py",r"C://Users//LENOVO//Desktop//python2021")
```

When i run the code that is no output shown ?

Is there a better way to check if a given file is within a specific directory and it's including subdirectories

Thanks

Comment: May be try `print(Grep("Test.py",r"C://Users//LENOVO//Desktop//python2021"))`?

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860153/how-do-i-get-the-parent-directory-in-python).

Comment: Print the last statement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no output because you're not printing anything. Try this as the last line:

```py
print(Grep("Test.py",r"C://Users//LENOVO//Desktop//python2021"))
```