# Jenkins showing fopen: No such file or directory, but file exists

Tags: python, file, jenkins, path

I'm trying to open a file from a python script which am running from jenkins. Both the files (which am trying to open and the python script) are in same location. But when am running the script, am getting error,

fopen: No such file or directory

am running

export PATH="/file path:$PATH"

in jenkins before running my script.

But still am getting the fopen error.

Am able to run the script from terminal

Comment: `PATH` is for executables search path, not for data files that you `open`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reliably open a file in the same directory as a Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060221/how-to-reliably-open-a-file-in-the-same-directory-as-a-python-script)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the $WORKSPACE var to have a full path for the fopen command.