# Python, Creating a new file/folder in the same directory as the script

Tags: python

I've written a script that basically creates two new folders when it's run the first time, if the folders don't already exist.

```
import os

try:
    os.makedirs('results/graphs')

except OSError:
    pass
```

And everytime the script is run, the graphs are produced in the `results/graphs` folder.

But I noticed recently that if the script is run from another directory, (eg. script is in `home/user/script/` but I run it from: `home/user/programs/`), the new folders are created in `home/user/programs/`.

My goal is ultimately that the folders are created only in the script folder and all eventual graphs that are produced will thus be destined to `home/user/script/results/graphs`.

Is there someway to achieve this using python?

I'm using Debian 8 and python 2.7.13. The graphs are produced using matplotlib.

Comment: Take a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918154/relative-paths-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reliably open a file in the same directory as a Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060221/how-to-reliably-open-a-file-in-the-same-directory-as-a-python-script)

Comment: Did you try `sys.path[0]` to get the location of the script?

Answer (score 2):

It's a solution for me, check it (I tried it on windows):

```
import os
d = os.path.dirname(__file__) # directory of script
p = r'{}/results/graphs'.format(d) # path to be created

try:
    os.makedirs(p)
except OSError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script `results/graphs` refers to the results folder within whatever folder you ran the script from. If you always want the folders to be created in `/home/user/script/results/graphs` use `~/script/results/graphs` in your script instead.  Alternatively you could hard code the whole path, `/home/user/script/results/graphs`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, apart from hard coding which is mentioned earlier. You can use **__file__** to extract the path of the file where the script is present. And then you can use it to append as parent path to **results/graphs**

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to define the path where your script is. This can be done within the code as:

```
path = 'home/user/script/'
```

or by getting the input from the user using a filedialog box.

Then you can use the path variable to make the directories.

```
os.makedirs(path + 'results/graphs')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
##creating folder
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

dirctry = os.path.dirname(file_path)
toolSharePath = os.path.abspath(dirctry)
final_directory = os.path.join(toolSharePath, r'new_folder')
if not os.path.exists(final_directory):
   os.makedirs(final_directory,exist_ok=True)
```