# Reading file from the same directory as the python module

Tags: python, file, path

Suppose I have got python module `foo.py` and file `myfile.txt` that reside in the same directory. `foo.py` contains the following code to read `myfile.txt`:

```
from os import path
myfile_path = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'myfile.txt')
myfile = open(myfile_path)
```

I found myself writing `path.join(path.dirname(__file__), '...')` over and over again in different modules. Is there a shorter and simpler way to read a file from the same directory as the python module ?

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060221/how-to-reliably-open-a-file-in-the-same-directory-as-a-python-script

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this applies to your exact situation, but here is what I have found:

There should be a JSON file that defines how the debugger should work. For me, I use VS Code, and I use the Microsoft Python debugger. It uses a file called launch.json, and contains an array called `"configurations"`:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "internalConsole"
]
```

It is missing a key called `"cwd"`, short for "current working directory" (you can read more about it [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)). If you add it with the value of blank quotes `""`, then when Python searches for a file without a specified path, it will search within the same folder. Showing the last few lines of what that looks like:

```
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "cwd": ""
]
```

For more general advice, your debugger, or whatever else is running your Python file, needs to have its working directory correctly defined.

I realize the post is nineteen months old at some point, but I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data = open('myfile.txt', 'r').read()`, without using path.

Comment: This won't work for when the file is a submodule