# in Python3, how could I import a python file which is reading a xml comfig?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python file, e.g. scan.py which needs to import util.py(in another folder). The util.py file is reading the xml configuration file

```
config = ET.parse("config.xml")
```

however, when I run scan.py, I get the error that "No such file or directory: 'config.xml'" how could I solve this kind of problem..?

Comment: where is your `config.xml` file located?

Comment: @Nihal the config.xml is in the same level with util.py, different folder with scan.py

Comment: Try giving the path as `Et.parse("./config.xml")`

Comment: see also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060221/how-to-reliably-open-a-file-in-the-same-directory-as-a-python-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative file paths (like your `'config.xml'`) are always relative to the directory you're calling the `python` executable. For instance:

```
D:\dev\projects\>python myapp.py
```

If `myapp.py` imports something from god-only-knows where that's looking for a file named `"childfolder/filename.ext"`, then it's actually looking for `D:\dev\projects\childfolder\filename.ext`.

If you need your file path to be relative to the script that is looking for it, you need to make it an *absolute* path. The easiest way to do this is by using `__file__`, which is a magical variable that contains the absolute path to the script that's running. You can use `os.path` to do this by getting the directory name of `__file__` (the directory your file lives in) then `join`ing it with the config.xml name:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "config.xml")
```

but `pathlib` makes this even easier.

```
# inside D:\dev\projects\myapp.py
configpath = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name("config.xml")
assert configpath == pathlib.Path(r"D:\dev\projects\config.xml")  # ta-da!
```

Comment: Thanks ! yes, pathlib really saves me !

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure both your xml file and your `scan.py` script are in the same folder.

Then you can basically use the commands:

```
src = open('config.xml')
parseddoc = parse(src) #to parse the opened file
```