# How to load a file in module without hard coding path

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a collection of functions in a module called `my_functions.py`.  One of these functions must load data from a text file that is stored in the same directory as `my_functions.py`.  For example:

```
# contents of my_functions.py
def func1():
    # first thing, load a file in same directory as my_functions.py
    data = open("blah.txt", "r").read()
```

If I import `my_functions` into `calling_code.py` and then call `func1` I get an error telling me `blah.txt` is not a file.  This occurs because `calling_code.py` is not in the same directory as `my_functions`.  I tried tricking `func1` to define it's relative path using this line from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4060259/1678467), but even this defines the path as the `calling_code.py`'s directory.

```
__location__ = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

The only other thing I can think of is to load `my_functions.py` in `func1` so I can then call it's `__file__` attribute.  e.g.

```
# contents of my_functions.py
def func1():
    # load my_functions.py
    import my_functions as mf
    root = os.path.dirname(my_functions.__file__)
    src = os.path.join(root, "blah.txt")

    # load a file in same directory as my_functions.py
    data = open(src, "r").read()
```

While this works, it seems like a bit of a hack.  Is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a design problem. If the location of `blah.txt` is fixed relative to `my_functions.py`, then `func1` cannot use a hard coded relative path, because it relates to the working directory, not to the location of the source code.

If you don't want to use `__file__`, other solutions are:

- Pass the path to `blah.txt` as an argument to `func1`:

  ```
  def func1(blah_path):
      data = open(blah_path, "r").read()
  ```
- Use an environment variable to specify the path to `blah.txt`:

  ```
  import os

  def func1():
      data = open(os.environ["FUNC1_BLAH_PATH"], "r").read()
  ```
- Replace `blah.txt` by a module containing the data and use a relative import:

  ```
  from . import blah

  def func1():
      data = blah.data
  ```

Comment: Well, I'm trying to avoid hard coding the path since I use this module on different systems (different servers at different times), so I'm trying to avoid rewriting the path each time I export the module to a new/different server (or use it locally).