# open() function returns directory error for no reason

Tags: python

I was making a project that has you type what's on the screen, and I was trying to get it to generate random words from a file. but I got an error saying `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'words.txt'`. I double-checked that the file was in the same directory and it was named right. Then I went back to my other program using this file, and it didn't work either (Even though it worked perfectly before). I tried using a shorter file to see if that was the problem, but it still gave me the same error.

Here is my (incomplete) code:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Entry
import random

words = open('words.txt')
tab = Tk()

words = words.readlines()

totype = words[random.randint(1, len(words))]

print(totype)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Same directory as what? Your terminal prompt working directory or your Python file?

Comment: Relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4060221/2308683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the directory you're running python from is the correct directory.

On python 3.4+, you can use the `pathlib` module to open files in the same directory as the script easily:

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(__file__).with_name('file.txt')
with p.open('r') as f:
    words = f.read()
```

You can check this with:

```py
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
```

And use the relative directory from that.

Alternatively, use the full directory.
You can get the full path of the script using:

```py
import os 
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Then you can use `dir_path + file_name` to get your full file path.

Comment: Do you mean `f.readlines()`?

Comment: Yeah, it was just an example for reading a file. You could `read` or `readlines` as per your requirements.

Comment: Is it possible to search the entire computer instead of just the current working directory?

Comment: Do you mean find a file in the computer in general? This post has information about using `os.walk()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You have to give directory path specifying where the file is located if the file is located in same directory as your script file you can do

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Entry
import random

words = open('./words.txt')
tab = Tk()

words = words.readlines()

totype = words[random.randint(1, len(words))]

print(totype)
```

if it is located in some other folder then you can do

```
file = open(r'C:\Users\Directory\sample.txt') #example

words = open(file)

tab = Tk()

words = words.readlines()

totype = words[random.randint(1, len(words))]

print(totype)
```