# VsCode don't run any image in python

Tags: python, image, visual-studio-code, python-turtle

My VsCode isn't running any image, i don't know why, and this happens with jpg too.
Here is my code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen=Screen()
screen.setup(600,600)
screen.bgpic(picname="olho.gif")


screen.exitonclick()
```

And the error is:

```
 $ c:/Users/User/Desktop/ProgramasPython/venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/User/Desktop/ProgramasPython/Cursopython/Day20/Day20.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\ProgramasPython\Cursopython\Day20\Day20.py", line 5, in <module>
    screen.bgpic(picname="olho.gif")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\turtle.py", line
1482, in bgpic
    self._bgpics[picname] = self._image(picname)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\turtle.py", line
478, in _image
    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename, master=self.cv)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4064, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4009, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "olho.gif": no such file or directory
```

Comment: "couldn't open "olho.py": no such file or directory"—well, does that file exist in the working directory? And is it actually an image file?

Comment: Chris, everything that i try to do with an image, give me an error, and my image is in my project paste

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Is a file called `olho.py` in the working directory? The error says it can't find that file.

Comment: A second issue that you'll likely hit as soon as you fix your image path is that images are rarely named with `.py` file extensions. Is that file actually an image? The documentation says this argument must refer to a GIF (or be `"nopic"` or `None`).

Comment: sorry i miss digit in the post, but in the code is if a .gif image

Comment: What do you mean by "in the code is if a .gif image"? This is pretty straightforward: is `olho.py` the name of a GIF file in the working directory?

Comment: i edit the post

Comment: You've changed the name of the file, but the problem remains the same. Is that file _in the working directory_ or somewhere else? (Note that the documentation specifically says you must use a GIF. Trying a JPEG is unlikely to work.) You've tagged VSCode—how are you running this code? Do you know what your working directory is?

Comment: But the image is in my project directory

Comment: I'm running with bash, and i know the working directory is

Comment: "I'm running with bash"—how, _exactly?_ Are you doing `cd c:/Users/User/Desktop/ProgramasPython/Cursopython/Day20/`, then running `python Day20.py`? I suspect not—your error message shows full paths to both the Python interpreter and your script. If you run `cwd`, what does it show you? The directory you are in, the one that is printed out when you run `cwd`, is your working directory, and I strongly suspect it doesn't contain the GIF you are trying to use.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45591428/354577. Assuming that is the case, you can either `cd` to the right directory before running your script or update your script to [find the GIF relative to the location of the Python file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4060221/354577) instead of the working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I tried as you wrote, and the problem you said will happen when I remove the file from the workspace.

Make sure that file name is consistent with the file name in the code, and whether the file is in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()   //Return a string representing the current working directory.
```

You can through the above code to get the search location of the file in the python interpreter.

The default value of the `cwd` in the VSCode was the `workspace` folder(the folder you opened in the VSCode), if the `olho.gif` does not under the workspace folder, the python interpreter can not find it. Such as it under the `Day20` folder.

But you can add this in the settings.json file to modify the `cwd` to the
parent folder of your executed python script.

```
"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,
```

Then if the `olho.gif` under the `Day20` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Python in VCSode does not recognize current directory images, but when I use the complete path the problem will resolve.

```
icon = PhotoImage(file="E:\\\Python Project\\\Vs Code\\\GUI Tkinter\\\Icon.png")
```

PS:
You got to use trible `\\\` for escape.