# I'm trying to build a chatbot, code returns only one error "Intents.JSON" file not found in directory

Tags: javascript, python, chatbot

[image]

I attached the image for reference. When I tested the model.py for the bot, it returns 0.0012 loss in epoch. I'm not very familiar with the language, so need some help

I'm trying to resolve that one issue. I need someone to review my code. I can share the git URL if requested

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Comment: use "./intents.json" when call open file

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to it. When you open the file by using only `./intents.json` or `intents.json` sometimes it can't find it because it runs the code from other directory.
Try this, I have adapted code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65174822/11839142:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(__file__).with_name('intents.json')
with p.open('r') as json_data:
    intents = json.load(json_data.read())
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your view. It still says file not found. Any other suggestions. Also, check the folders structure.  does it need any changes?

Comment: Hey, I found this other solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65174822/11839142. Try this, hope it helps! I will update my answer and if it works I ask for you to mark it as the correct answer, thanks!