# How to move a file in a directory to another in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a File that needs to be moved by my python script with shutil but I don't know where the origin location is, how do I find the origin location?

```
import shutil
import os

name = os.getlogin()

shutil.move(./file.foo, 'C:/Users/'+name+'/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup')
```

the "file.foo" is in the same directory as my python script

I have searched everywhere but I cant get a good result even with `os.path` and others.

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reliably open a file in the same directory as the currently running script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060221/how-to-reliably-open-a-file-in-the-same-directory-as-the-currently-running-scrip)

Answer (score 0):

use `shutil.move` method to move a file `shutil.move(src, dst, copy_function=copy2)`

> Recursively move a file or directory (src) to another location (dst) and return the destination. [refer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

```
source = 'path/to/file'
destination = 'path/to/file'
dest = shutil.move(source, destination, copy_function = shutil.copytree)
```