# File not found error despite the script and the texture folder are in the same folder

Tags: python

It reports a filenotfound error when I enter the following code:

```
background = pygame.image.load('Art/base_vision.jpg')
```

The report was `No file 'Art/window_icon.png' found in working directory 'C:\Users\xxx'`

However, the directory of the script is `c:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Game/Pygame test`, and all of the art used in the project is in `c:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Game/Pygame test/Art`. It will simply not take files in the folder "`Art`", instead it will only take what's in `C:/Users/xxx`.

This is a group project I'm sending to team members, so the script needs to use files in its folder instead on `C:`.

Comment: This will look for the subfolder `Art` in _the current directory_, which is NOT necessarily the same directory as your python script.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4060221/494134

Answer (score 0):

use

`background = pygame.image.load("./Art/base_vision.jpg")`

./ will let your program know that it is a relative path and use your current working directory

Comment: `Art` and `./Art` are exactly equivalent.  This is not the reason.

Comment: This resulted in the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell python to use the path of the current script and join it with the image relative path.

```py
import os
script_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_relative_path = 'Art\\base_vision.jpg'
background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(script_directory , image_relative_path))
```

whenever you write `__file__` in a script it will always have the absolute path of the file where this variable is.

if you don't specify the absolute path of the file `C:\users\...` then python will look for files relative to your current working directory, [what is current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory).

Comment: it is resolved! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python's built-in `pathlib` library deals with this issue nicely. Here is an example of how your script.py could look, given a folder structure like you describe

```
Game/
├─ Pygame test/
│  ├─ script.py
│  ├─ Art/
│  │  ├─ art.png
```

```py
from pathlib import Path

import pygame

SCRIPT_PATH = Path(__file__).resolve() # get the path of the script
PYGAME_PATH = SCRIPT_PATH.parents[0] # parents gives a list of parent directories, get the first one
ART_PATH = PYGAME_PATH / "Art" # the division operator for Path objects concatenates a Path object with a string

background = pygame.image.load(ART_PATH / "art.png")
```

Most libraries will accept Path objects, but in case they don't, you can always cast them back to a string by calling the as_posix method `PATH_OBJECT.as_posix()`.

Also note that you shouldn't ever use backslashes when dealing with paths. The backslash has a special meaning in Python as an escape character. Python is smart enough to interpret forward slashes correctly, even on Windows (but using Path objects is pretty much as cross-platform as you will get, and provides a bunch of convenience functions as well).