# Simple python exe app doest not wrtite text to selected file whenever is stared by Task scheduller

Tags: python, text, scheduled-tasks, fwrite, windows-task-scheduler

This is my simple code:

```
f = open("mytext.txt", "a")
f.write("Now the file has more content!")
f.close()
```

When I start it by Task Scheduller, I don´t see any error, but text is not wrotten in file after that. When I run exe or py file manually. It works normally.

Comment: Does it write that file to the system32 folder by chance? I believe that is the default working directory.

Comment: @JonSG I am sorry but what do you mean? Both my files are in C:\Users\mirek\myfile

Comment: The default working dir for app scheduler tasks is system32

Comment: So I need place files to system32 folder?

Comment: I added to system32 folder but still not work.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060221/how-to-reliably-open-a-file-in-the-same-directory-as-the-currently-running-scrip

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to check a couple of things:

1. **See if the directory your program runs in is correct:**
   Properties -> Action -> Double-click on "start a program" -> Check the path in "start in (optional):" setting.
   It could be that scheduler runs your exe in a different directory (and creates the file there)
2. **Check if User you run this task as has the rights to write in desired directory:**
   Properties -> General -> Security options -> "When running the task, use the following user account:" that's the user that needs permission to write data in directory.
   Then, go to your directory and check:
   Properties -> Security -> %user% -> Writing is allowed.

Comment: In the second part I think everything is ok. https://ibb.co/vkD0G4Q. And for the first one, in which directory I tried to add another directory but problem is the same.