# Getting a 'No such file' on an old python script that used to work flawlessly

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with a python script that has the following line:

`reference=open("./reference.txt","r")`

This would read a reference text file for later use to write in another file. But transferring the project folder from one device to another has caused this specific line to stop functioning. I assume the "./" allowed the script to open the file relative to the python script's parent folder. But it doesn't seem to work like this anymore.

I do remember using `__file__` back when I was working with the person who wrote the script and it wasn't working for us at the time. We tried importing from both os.path and pathlib respectively to no avail. Eventually we used `./` in front of our file, and it worked. At the time we were transferring the project folder between our two devices and we had the folder saved in drastically different file paths so this helped a lot. But now I'm trying to re-use this script a few months later on another device and it's not happening.

In the end I would like to just print out the contents of the reference text file as I think I can take it from there, maybe.

Something like:

```
import os

reference=open("./reference.txt","r")

print(reference)
```

I tried to run a python script with a relative file path and visual studio code's terminal spits out an error saying "No such file or directory:"

Was expecting the file to just be read by the python script just fine considering this script worked in the past in two different devices with the project folder saved in different file paths.

Comment: "I assume the "./" allowed the script to open the file relative to the python script's parent folder. " - This is not - and never was - the case. It is relative to your current working directory.

Comment: How are you running the script, and from where? Do you know what the interpreter's current working directory is? If not, you can find out with `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060221/how-to-reliably-open-a-file-in-the-same-directory-as-the-currently-running-scrip or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-do-you-properly-determine-the-current-script-directory  answer your question?

Comment: What is the difference between the parent folder and the "current working directory"? I don't know how to reply directly here. As for those reference links, I do remember looking over those two and neither did the trick for us at the time. Not certain why.

Answer (score -1):

Check that your working directory is the correct folder using `os.getcwd()`
If your script is in the same folder as `reference.txt` you can get the absolute path using:

```
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

`__file__` returns the path of the file where the `__file__` function is executed and `os.path.dirname()` gets the path name of the sub folder of the path specified.