# FileNotFoundError although it is in the correct directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

I want to open a file with python in vscode but there is a FileNotFoundError.
I have the txt-file in the same directory as the python file.
I deleted the file and than wrote it again in the right directory but it didn't help.

[image]

[image]

The path is correct and it works when I use import os.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not opening `VSCode` in the same directory as you have your codes. As you can see in the terminal, the path that you are running the code from is :

`C:\Users\Raoul\Documents\Python\Visual Studio Code`

Where possibly in this path there is no `story.txt` file. Now what can you do to address this issue? There are two possible ways :

##### 1. Without using terminal

You can go to the directory and right-click on an empty place in that directory and select `Open with Code`, then run your code :

[image]

##### 2. Using terminal

You can navigate in terminal to the directory that your code is, then write :

`code .`

Which means open VSCode in this directory. Then run your code without any problem. There are more sources that you can read and learn this way of opening VSCode, like [this link](https://vscode.one/start-vscode-from-terminal/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your working directory is C:\Users\Raoul\Documents\Python\Visual Studio Code but your file reside in another directory.

Try changing the working directory to the same directory where your python and txt files reside.

Try this:

```
import os
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Raoul\Documents\Python\Visual Studio Code\projects\mini_projects_9h")
```

Answer (score 0):

It most likely doesn't work because of the folder from which you run the file. This folder will be used as the current working directory and therefore a local reference doesn't work. You can try this by running it from the folder the script is in: "C:\Users\Raoul\Documents\Python\Visual Studio Code\projects\mini_projects_9h"

This solution elaborates more on this: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060221/how-to-reliably-open-a-file-in-the-same-directory-as-the-currently-running-scrip)

Answer (score 0):

You could open your settings and search for Execute In File Dir.

Checking this option will allow you to run the file in the folder where the file is located

[image]