# How to know the filename of script.py while executing it with ironpython

Tags: python

i would like to get the name of the "file.py" that I am executing with ironpython.
I have to read and save data to other files with the same name start.

Thank you very much!

Humano

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, how do I get the path and name of the file that is currently executing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/in-python-how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `__file__`.
You can use `os.path.basename(__file__)`