# Difference between import and execfile

Tags: python-2.7, import, python-import, execfile

I have a file `utils.py` containing a function called `f1()`.

From another Python script I can `import utils` or `execfile('utils.py')` and have access to `f1()`. What are the differences between the two methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many differences, but from your point of view the most significant is probably that `import` gives you more control over the namespace in which the objects defined in `utils.py` end up.

Let's consider three variants on `import`.  The first is the one you asked about:

```
import utils
utils.f1()
```

`utils` is the only symbol that has been added to your workspace—any pre-existing `f1` in your base workspace will not have been overwritten, and if there is none, then `f1()` on its own will not be recognized.  For code I intend to maintain, I greatly prefer this way of importing, because it makes it easy for me to search my source file for all the places in which it depends on `utils`.

But if saying `utils.f1()` every time is too verbose then you can do this:

```
from utils import f1
f1()
```

Now if you say `f1()` that will call `utils.f1()`, because that is the code object that you have now associated with the name `f1` in your workspace. It's now slightly harder to get an overview of where your code is reliant on the `utils` module. But at least this type of `import` statement gives you precise control over which symbols were imported and which not.   You can even rename symbols during this process:

```
from utils import f1 as EffOne
EffOne()
```

Finally you can choose to lose control over the namespace entirely:

```
from utils import *
```

Now, who knows what symbols have been imported: basically everything that `utils` has to offer the world (or, if the `utils` developer took the trouble to specify an `__all__` attribute, then everything listed there).  I'd advise you to use `import *` only for quick-and-dirty programming, if at all.

This is actually the importing style that is closest to `execfile` from the namespace point of view: `execfile('utils.py')` does much the same as `from utils import *` in that it dumps all symbols defined by `utils` willy-nilly into your workspace.  One slight difference is that `execfile` won't even limit itself to the symbols in `__all__` if that is defined—in fact, the `__all__` symbol itself will just get dumped in your lap along with everything else.

Beyond namespaces, there are still plenty of differences between `from utils import *` and `execfile('utils.py')`.  One is caching: a second `import` call on `utils` will be very fast (the code will not be re-run), but a second call to `execfile('utils.py')` may take just as long as the first because the code *will* be re-run.   Also, there may be some code (often test code) inside `utils.py` that the `utils` author does not want to run at import time, but *only* when the file is executed via `execfile`.   Such code is placed inside an `if __name__ == '__main__':` clause.

Comment: `execfile` is dead—long live `exec(open('utils.py').read())`  and IPython's `%run utils`.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/436198/