# Python - Find a path to the file of a program being run

Tags: python, scripting, ipc

How would I find the path to the file of a program?

For example: If I have sublime open, and have a text file open inside it

How would I get the file path of the text file?

Is it possible to do it to a web browser to get the links in the tabs. or Microsoft word?

Any help is appreciated

Edit: I want a python script that can get paths of the currently executed file to be used for transferring over network

Comment: Your question is a little too broad and will probably get flagged. I would revise it, narrow the scope of what you are asking, and be be more clear and descriptive in what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is answered in this thread:
[How do I get the path and name of the file that is currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing)

Also, here is some documentation that answers your question http://www.faqs.org/docs/diveintopython/regression_path.html