# Get the directory of where my script is stored

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script that has to execute a shell script. In my GIT repo I have plans to commit both (Python program + Shell script) in same directory in my repo.

My issue is that when someone pulls out my code and wants to run my Python script from any relative / absolute location - I need to refer the shell script in the directory where my Python script resided.

I am not sure which one I should make use of

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
OR
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
OR
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

If I run my python script in same directory it prints same values - even if I execute from a separate directory and run my script as mentioned below I still get same values:

```
 python ./test/test1/1.py

/x/home02/myhome/test/test1
```

If it so which one I should actually make use of? What is the difference in between each of them?

========== Updated =========

I created a symbolic link to my code like as mentioned below:

```
cd
ln -s /x/home02/myhome/test/test1/1.py 2.py
```

Now when I re-run my code as mentioned below -

```
cd
python 2.py
cd test
python ../2.py
```

I get the below output

```
/x/home02/myhome/test/test1
/x/home02/myhome
/x/home02/myhome
```

So I think the below one is the correct one as I am always getting the expected output:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Comment: Your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31867043

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first you want the directory, so let's use `os.path.dirname(...)`

And `os.path.abspath(__file__)` should get you the path of the script, the difference between this and `os.path.realpath()` is the latter eliminates symbolic links, so not sure if you want that

So I'd use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

Comment: Please see my updated findings in my question .. thanks for giving the correct steps to resolve symbolic links protection in my code

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `os.path.realpath` and `os.path.abspath` is the former eliminates symbolic links whereas the latter be the absolute path of a symbolic link.

In this case, the order of `os.path.dirname` and `abspath` or `realpath` shouldn't matter -- It would only matter if the file you passed in didn't have a directory portion.

Answer (score 0):

You should use absolute path with directory name of pathname, like this:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Find the common pathname manipulations (os.path) documentation to find the difference between the usage here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html