# how to get script name when using execfile() in IPython to run script

Tags: python, ipython, python-2.x, args

Hello stackoverflow community,

How can I get the script name when using execfile() in IPython to run the script?

**Demonstration**:

I've created this script (named `printScriptName.py`)

```
import os,sys
print os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
```

This is the output when running it using IPython:

```
In [37]: execfile('printScriptName.py')
ipython-script.py
```

Which is obviously not `printScriptName.py`.

Thanks.

Comment: @Cilyan the asnwers on the mentioned thread return ipython-script.py in my case -- which is not the desired output.

Comment: Indeed. See here then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing