# how to pass filename to the variable in Python

Tags: python, shell

I am new to Python and recently I am working on Shell Scripting.
In Shell Scripting if I want to pass filename to variable then I am passing like

```
myScriptName="`/bin/basename $0`"
```

Is it possible to same in Python??

Comment: Try to look at console args in python: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm

Comment: It is not about argument. I want to pass whole file path in one variable @vanadium23

Comment: Aww, I see, something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please give more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about path of the file:
You can use a call to OS method `__file__` to accomplish this. This will bring in extension also.

```
import os

fileName = os.path.basename(__file__)
print fileName
```

If you want full path  with filename assigned to a variable:

```
import sys

file2= sys.argv[0]
print file2
```