# Getting unicode path of current running script

Tags: python, unicode

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing) question exists on this website but it is flawed as it returns a `<type 'str'>` (both when using `__file__` and when using the module `inspect`) and not a `<type 'unicode'>` which I need as my path contains non-ascii characters (Hebrew characters, to be specific).

How can I get the path and filename of current running script in `<type 'unicode'>` in the file system encoding? Is there any Unicode-friendly function built-in for doing so or any solution?

Just calling `__file__.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())` fails with `ascii codec can't decode byte ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `.decode()`, not `.encode()`. To go from `unicode` to `str`, one *encodes*. To go the other direction, one *decodes*.

Try:

```
import sys
filename = __file__.decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
print type(filename), filename
```

Result:

```
$ python 'קוֹבֶץ.py'
<type 'unicode'> קוֹבֶץ.py
```

Comment: It all makes sense now! Thank you so much

Comment: @Jonathan: note: the error in your question is due to `.encode()` method tries to *decode* your bytestring using `sys.getdefaultencoding()` (that should be  ascii on Python 2) before encoding it using `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` that works for representable characters (on Linux, your local settings should be correct).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use `decode` instead of `encode`:

```
>>> type('string'.encode('utf-8'))
<type 'str'>
>>> type('string'.decode('utf-8'))
<type 'unicode'>
```

Genrally, `encode` returns a bytestring, `decode` a unicode object.