# QPushButton set image, image doesn't apear

Tags: qt, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt

I am setting image (25x25 original size) on a QPushButton like this:icon =

```
QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("pause.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
```

also tried this:

```
self.pushButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("pause.png"))
```

also `"/pause.png"` and nothing works. Im sure ive tried several more things i saw online and in all it compiles but there is no image on the button. Tried setting imagesize like this:

```
self.pushButton.setIconSize(QSize(24, 24))
```

and there is no change. 
Using pycharm + qt5.7

Comment: If you are using images for icons I would strongly recommend using Qt's [resource collection files](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html#resource-collection-files-op-op-qrc). This would not only make accessing the files easier but make your application more portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming the current working directory of the process by providing a relative path to the image. As you've noticed, your assumption is wrong. Use an absolute path referenced to e.g. the [application's location](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50499/1329652):

```
// Python
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))) 
  + QDir.separator() + "pause.png"`
```

```
// C++
QCoreApplication.applicationDirPath() + QDir.separator() + "pause.png"`
```

Comment: You were more than helpful. Thanks