# How to handle filepaths?

Tags: python

I discovered that a script's "current working directory" is, initially, not the where the script is located, but rather where the *user* is when he/she runs the script.

If the script is at `/Desktop/Projects/pythonProject/myscript.py`, but I'm at `/Documents/Arbitrary` in my terminal when I run the script, then that's going to be it's present working directory, and an attempt at `open('data.txt')` is going to give File Not Found because it's not looking in the right directory.

So how is a script supposed to open files if it can't know where it's being run from? How is this handled?

My initial thought was to use absolute paths. Say my script needs to open `data.txt` which is stored alongside it in its package `pythonProject`. Then I would just say `open('/Desktop/Projects/pythonProject/data.txt')`.

But then you can't ever move the project without editing every path in it, so this can't be the right solution.

Or is the answer simply that you *must* be in the directory where the script is located whenever you run the script? That doesn't seem right either.

Is there some simple manipulation for this that I'm not thinking of? Are you just supposed to `os.chdir` to the script's location at the beginning of the script?

Comment: You can use `__file__` to determine the script's location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the path and name of the file that is currently executing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the current file's directory path, using `os.path.dirname`, `os.path.abspath`, `os.path.realpath`, and the `__file__` variable:

```
import os
file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Then, to create cross-platform filepaths, use `os.path.join()`:

```
os.path.join(file_dir, "test.txt")
```

Alternatively, you can change the current working directory to the running file's directory so you don't have to `os.path.join` every time:

```
os.path.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
```

---

Why use `os.path.abspath` *and* `os.path.realpath`? The inner `realpath` resolves symbolic links, while the `abspath` resolves relative paths. If you know for sure no symbolic links are being used, you can omit this inner `realpath` call.

Comment: This is a good answer, but scripts are more useful if they accept the name of files to act on as command-line parameters and only use these techniques to locate static files they need to operate.

Comment: Accepting dynamic filenames as command-line parameters does not seem to be in the scope of the question asked.

Comment: That is why I added my thoughts as a comment.  The question did not seem to consider accepting a filename as an alternative, when in fact it is a common pattern.  Your answer is a good one for the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

A module's location is always available in the `__file__` variable. You can use the functions in `os.path` (I'm mainly thinking of basedir and join) to transform module-relative paths to absolute paths