# How to save matplotlib plot with the same file name as its filename.py

Tags: python, matplotlib

I run the python code for Matplotlib plotting from thisfilename.py. Is there a variable that stores this filename without file path? As I want to save the plot as thisfilename.png without typing the file name like this every time?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  ...
  plt.savefig('thisfilename.png')
```

I want to change the last line to something like

```
  # pseudocode
  plt.savefig(variable, '.png')
```

I tested

```
  plt.savefig(__file__, ".png")
```

The saved filename had .py, the file path, and the space before .png which I don't want

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing#1955163)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the figure with same name as the python file, replacing the ".py" by ".png" and removing the path, I would use :

```
plt.gcf().savefig(__file__.rstrip('.py').split('/')[-1] + ".png")
```

the rstrip removes ".py" from the right side of the **file** string,
the split method separate your chains at each "/" and [-1] keeps only the last item of the list
the + can be used to concatenate strings

Answer (score 1):

```
import inspect
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

frame = inspect.currentframe()
path = inspect.getfile(frame)
fname = path.split('.')[0]

t = np.linspace(0,1, 1000)
plt.plot(t, np.sin(2*np.pi*t*4))
plt.savefig(fname + ".jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's [`splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext) to break `__file__` into two parts and then add the required extension as follows:

```
import os

output_filename = os.path.splitext(__file__)[0] + '.png'
plt.savefig(output_filename)
```