# Global Name for the directory of Project

Tags: python

I'm making an e-mail sending script in Python, in which the code for the attachment is as follows:

```
filename = "Output.txt"
attachment = open("/root/Desktop/test/output/project/file.txt", "rb")
```

Now, the problem is the directory output has been changed as per the name of my project. So is there any way that I can use a global name for this?

Comment: If I understand correctly you're looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing)?

Comment: No sir this is far diff from it. My script of sending mail is in /test folder while my output file is in  /test/output/project_name folder

Comment: So you're asking how to define a global variable so that it can be used in the whole module?

Comment: See as per new projects arrives, my attachment path will be diff.. like for project-1 it may b /output/project1/doc1.txt and for project-2 it may b /output/project2/doc2.txt so I need to define a global varibale for project directory to define it in path of attachment

Comment: So something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034496/using-global-variables-between-files), then?