# How can I get the working directory of my script if I am using atom editor?

Tags: python

I want to show the directory of my script but is not working with the answers I've founded.

I've tried with several answers, but this one was the most repeated one:

```py
import os
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('__file__'))
```

Still it isn't giving me the desired output, is giving me the working directory:

```py
C:\Users\my_user\Desktop
```

But I'm working inside a folder in desktop, desired output:

```py
C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\working_folder
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly determine current script directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718657/how-to-properly-determine-current-script-directory)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5137509/5665958)?

Comment: those solutions are not working, that's why I posted a different topic

Comment: What do you mean by "not working", `os.getcwd()` gives you the working directory. If it is giving you a different directory than you expected, then your working directory is not what you think

Comment: I don't want the working directory, I want the directory of the file. When I open the file I want to set the location of the file as the working directory.

Comment: Can you add the path where your scripts are located?

Comment: C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\working_folder

Comment: C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\working_folder\script.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure i got it right now :

```
import os
path = os.path.realpath(__file__) 
filename= os.path.basename(__file__) 
print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), filename))
```

Comment: I get: 
NameError: name '__ file __ ' is not defined

Comment: it's the dunder, `__file__`

Comment: are you trying from shell directly ? try with a python file that you exec then it'll work ! ( the __file__ var is set thanks to filepath, which is not set in shell

Comment: Okay, from the shell is working! Why is not working on Atom editor?

Comment: If I use the shell is working, but with Atom editor is not.

Comment: what do you mean by atom editor ? Are you executing your file from it ? or manually ? because if you wrote a proper file with the shebang like this it must work                                                                                                                 `#! /usr/bin/python3
import os
path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
filename = os.path.basename(__file__)
print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(path), filename))`

Comment: it's strange, maybe the package is not executing the python code the "conventional way", if you can try to run your code directly from shell `python3 myfile.py ` for example, we will know if it's because of hydrogen

Comment: Can it be because is executing ipython?

Comment: yup i checked and the same problem occurs, with Ipython and shell it's the same reason, the variable can't be initialized, it must be ran in a file :)

Answer (score 0):

print os.path.realpath(__file__) is what you need i think please check this link for more on printing filepath [How do I get the path and name of the file that is currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing)