# Is there a Pythonic way to get the git tag of an imported module

Tags: python, git, import

I have a library of functions (`krypton`) which I have recently moved into its own Python 3.7 site package (in `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\krypton`). I would like to keep track of the version number of the package using git tags, as it forms part of the output when the package executes. I am using GitPython to do this.

So I need to find the directory in which the `krypton` code is located in a reliable way in order to pass it to the GitPython `Repo()` method, as otherwise the CWD from which the script which imports would be used.

What I have so far is

```
import krypton
directory = os.path.split(krypton.__file__)[0]

repo = git.Repo(directory)
__sha__ = repo.head.object.hexsha
tags = repo.tags
if tags:
    __version__ = repo.tags[-1].name
else:
    __version__ = "unknown"
```

So I am importing krypton.py within itself. Which doesn't feel right, but which *seems* to work OK. is there a more elegant/reliable/Pythonic way I should do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can skip the re-import by using `inspect` to get the path of the library itself. I found some stuff in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6628348/836748).