# vscode get path of current file from inside python script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, interactive

When ran from a terminal, sys.argv[0] is the path of current script, but in python interactive that variable points to "/some/path/ipykernel_launcher.py" which is a temporary file.

How do I get the path of current script (which I am editing in vscode)? I need this information because whenever I create a file, I automatically log which script created it. For that, I overload the open() function to automatically log the creation. But when file is created from a python interactive session, I am missing such information.

Comment: Maybe `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: Use the `__file__` variable or the `inspect` module. Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing).

Comment: Thanks @koorkevani! The `inspect` strategy in that answer doesn't work, but `__file__` does!

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
```

I think that's what you want. It prints the current working directory.

Comment: Sorry, but that gives the execution path, which, by the way, I usually set with `os.chdir(some_dir)` . It is true that at start of the interactive session, the `os.getcwd()` is that of the script. ... Anyway, I am missing the filename.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that works for me, obtained from [How do I get the path and name of the file that is currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing) is this:

`os.path.realpath(__file__)`

I tried all other suggestions, but didn't work.