# How to handle invoke commands running from any subdirectory?

Tags: python

[Invoke](https://www.pyinvoke.org/) seems to be clever enough that I can be in any subdirectory and call an invoke task. However I'm wondering how to ensure that the tasks run the same way without a lot of path massaging.

So for example, my structure is

```
code/
code/server/
code/tasks/build.py
```

I usually run `inv build.test` from the `code/` directory which then does the following:

```
    with c.cd('server/'):
        c.run('python manage.py test')
```

However if I'm in `code/server/` I can also run `inv build.run` and while it's nice that it finds the task definition, obviously it fails because it can't `cd server/`.

Is there a clean way to handle this other than splicing paths together?

Comment: I would look at info in this link, and use the full directory path for the build.py file and then "cd <dirpath>/../server"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing

Comment: @KoryGill thanks. So invoke has kind of a root location and I'm not sure how to access that. 

So if I'm in `code/server`, I'm looking for a command to return `code/` which is the "root directory" (looking for a command that returns it in a non hardcoded way) but `__file__` returns `code/server/build.py` and `os.cwd` returns `code/server/` neither of which is the invoke __root__.

Comment: from the `__file__` path, don't you know that code/ is always 2 directories up?  like "__file__/../.."

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've done, but I was hoping the `invoke` package had something specific because it does provide settings to change that root so I was hoping they'd exposed it in their package in some way. This works for now though, and i'm asking in their github as well.