# CSV not detecting file within same folder as program

Tags: python

I'm currently doing an assignment that requires me to use CSV files in Python. I have the .csv file in the same directory as the program itself, yet it gives me the same "No such file or directory" error.

I am sure the name is not a problem. This problem has happened to me before with another file and I wasn't able to fix that either.

Code:

```
with open('file.csv') as file:
        content = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.csv'
```

Comment: to help, we will need to see the code you are running, or at least the relevant part of it

Comment: @scotscotmcc that's my bad, i edited the post.

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing then you can extract the directory of the script and join it with the filename to an absolute path.

Comment: how are you calling the program? directly from the terminal with `python program.py`?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using the OS library for python.
Change the current working directory with:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))))
```

This changes Python's working directory to the one that your file is contained in.