# python packaging : accessing binaries from a different folder other than the package folder

Tags: python, directory, subprocess, setuptools, python-packaging

I have the following directory structure:

```
project
├── LICENSE.srt
├── README.md
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
└── src
    ├── bin
    │   └── a.out
    └── package
        ├── __init__.py
        └── module.py
```

I am trying to package the above python project with setuptools.
I want to execute the `a.out` file from `module.py` for which I am using the subprocess module.

How can I get the path for the `a.out` file?

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing then you can extract the directory of the module and join it with the relative path to "a.out" to an absolute path.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks, but file system paths don't work once we build this into a distribution such as a wheel.