# Python custom package: how to specify paths of yaml files within the package?

Tags: python

I want to create a python package with below folder structure:

```
/package
  /package
    __init__.py
    /main
      __init__.py
      main.py
      ...
    /data
      __init__.py
      constants.py  <--
      data.yml
  pyproject.toml
  ...
```

And inside `constants.py`, I defined the path to `data.yml`:
`DATA_PATH = './data.yml'` and used it in `main.py`:

```
from package.data.constants import DATA_PATH

with open(DATA_PATH, 'r') as f:
    ...
```

Then I build and installed the package into another project.

But when some code of `main` is used, it complains about "No such file or directory".

I also tried `'./data/data.yml'` and `'./package/data/data.yml'`and none worked.

How should I define the path?

Comment: The problem is that main.py could be run from any working directory. You could use [`os.path` and `__file__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499/how-do-i-get-the-path-and-name-of-the-file-that-is-currently-executing) to find the location of `constants.py` when that is running, and add `data.yaml` to that path

Answer (score 0):

You assign the string literal `'./data.yml'` to the variable `DATA_PATH`. In `main.py` Python addresses that as a relative path, searching for a file named `data.yml` within the directory `main.py` is in (.../package/main/).

You can assign the absolute path of `data.yml` instead. So in `constants.py`:

```
import os

...

DATA_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'data.yml')
```