# setuptools pyproject.toml - managing paths of enclosed config files

Tags: python, setuptools, pyproject.toml

When using pyproject.toml setuptools how can I dynamically assure that my binary finds its config enclosed in the same directory as the python code?

After pip install files are located:

```
:
c:\dist\venvs\ranchercli\lib\site-packages\ranchercli\ranchercli-projects.json
c:\dist\venvs\ranchercli\lib\site-packages\ranchercli\ranchercli.py
c:\dist\venvs\ranchercli\scripts\ranchercli.exe
:
```

But when I run:

```
# same dir:
ranchercli.exe --ns='keycloak' --env=prod --refresh
20240322095209.115|ERROR|C:\dist\venvs\ranchercli\Lib\site-packages\ranchercli\ranchercli.py:89|--projectfile=./ranchercli-projects.json not found
# relative:
20240322101246.345|ERROR|C:\dist\venvs\ranchercli\Lib\site-packages\ranchercli\ranchercli.py:89|--projectfile=../lib/site-packages/ranchercli/ranchercli-projects.json not found
```

I only got full path working but the path changes with any install:

`C:\\dist\\venvs\\ranchercli\\Lib\\site-packages\\ranchercli\\ranchercli-projects.json`

Comment: "*…the same directory as the python code…*" You should calculate it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1955163/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+open+file+script+directory

Comment: You should never rely on the value of `__file__` for this. You should use [*`importlib.resources`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood how this specifically related to `setuptools` as this seems to be a runtime behaviour (`setuptools` deals with build-time behaviour).

Possibly `importlib.resources` (and its backfill [`importlib_resources`](https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html)) can help here.

The function `importlib_resources.files("<NAME OF YOUR ROOT PACKAGE>")` should allow you to traverse all the files inside of your package installation.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround like @phd suggests, is to get the path from `__file__` with pathlib

```
parser.add_argument('--projectfile', help="json projectlist file", default='./ranchercli-projects.json')

:
if not os.path.isfile(args.projectfile):
  if args.projectfile.startswith('.'):
    args.projectfile = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute() / pathlib.Path(args.projectfile)
    if not os.path.isfile(args.projectfile):
      log.error(f"--projectfile={args.projectfile}, not found")
      sys.exit(-1)
```

But I need to do this for all files, Would like to have a generic way in setuptools.